# Detecting when a youtube video finishes in Android

Tags: android, youtube

I´m making in app in android using youtube api. The app shows a youtube video and then I want to do a question about the video after the user watches it. I  would like to know who can I detect the end of the video in order to start one activity with a question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a callback when video has completed if you are using the youtube API.
So by ovveriding the following you can implement your code,

```
@Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        //Put your code here
    }
```

Comment: thanks AHegde I have implemented  PlayerStateChangeListener in my activity class as well . But the answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we need to implement our activity/fragment with YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener

Then we shall get the @Override method of onVideoEnded() as with some other methods like:

```
@Override
    public void onLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        //Put your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

    }
```