# How to be notified when a video finishes playing in the official Android YouTube app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I know that when using a YouTubePlayerFragment or YoutubePlayerView, I can use YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener to receive onVideoEnded(). Is it possible to be notified similarly when the official android youtube app finishes playing a video?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this [`YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener) that you mention is the one that will tell you if the Youtube video is already finished.

Another way to achieve this problem is explained in these SO questions:

- [Detecting when a YouTube video has finished playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686745/detecting-when-a-youtube-video-has-finished-playing)
- [Detecting when a youtube video finishes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291619/detecting-when-a-youtube-video-finishes-in-android)